# Linking Application to static version of QT

Tags: qt, static, build

I'm new to QT and I've been trying to compile a static build of QT of DAYS (literally) I'm pretty much out of Ideas and the QT documentation is probably the least helpful I have ever read. It doesn't work out of the box thats the problem. It needs to be tweaked a considerable amount before you can compile it as static. Finally the other night I managed to compile it statically and then followed the instructions to deploy it. I then copied the executable to another machine where it promptly complained for the lack of dll msvcp100. WTF! I thought that the static build was dependency free! Can you guys give me a definitive answer that can solve my problems?

Comment: Is there a simple deployment method that I can just quickly use? I'm using Windows 7. the reason I started QT was because I wanted to escape the limitations of the .Net framework which was having to install it on every computer to run the app. I hope this isn't the case with the vc++ runtime libraries...

Comment: Are you developing with visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

That's the Visual C++ runtime library, not QT. You need to install http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84&displaylang=en